# Where is the Chrome Extensions list

Tags: google-chrome

I can't the work out how to view Google Chrome extensions.  I was working on solving other problems in Chrome and wanted to ensure that a problem extension was completely deleted.  Other directions I've found seem to be outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Click the three horizontal bars on the top right of Chrome (under the close window button in Windows).  Click More Tools->Extensions.
This Extensions list keeps moving around in the menus as they develop it; not certain why.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. Apparently I had an update for Chrome in queue. Deleted my answer.